# Как при вызове соответствующей коллекции превратить String из списка в переменную?

Tags: python, sql, mongodb

У меня есть список коллекций в БД:
Вот этот список:

```
collections = 
    ['metaCompanies',
     'personas',
      ...,
     'companies',
     'teamInvites',
     'activitySubjects']
```

Как видите каждая коллекция есть String в списке
Далее, я хочу пройтись по каждой из коллекций и вытянуть из нее список ключей.
Вот код:

```
lst = []
for i in collections:
    s = db.i.find_one().keys()
    lst.append([i,s])
```

Я получаю ошибку: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Мне понятна ошибка, так как в выражении `s = db.i.find_one()`, i - это строка, а должна быть перемення.
Т. е. если я задам эту строку вот так: `db.metaCompanies.find_one()`, то все заработает. Но, мне этот вариант не подходит, так список длинный и я не хочу все делать вручную.
Как мне строку превратить в переменную так, чтобы код заработал?
Спасибо

Comment: `getattr(db, i).find_one()`?

Comment: сработало) спасибо